# React child component won't recieve props

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a function like shown below:

```js
export function FileTrees ({
  structures,
  setValue,
}: {
  structures: Structure;
  setValue: Dispatcher<string>;
}
 ) {
  let [data, setData] = useState<Array<{}>>([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const incoming = convertObject(structures);
    setData(incoming);
  }, [structures]);
  // console.log(setValue)
  console.log(structures)

  return (
    <Tree
      children={null}
      data={data}
      onUpdate={handleUpdate}
      onNodeClick={(node) => {
        if (node.node.type === "file") {
          let path = node.node?.path;
          let name = node.node?.name; 
          setValue("hi mom")

        }}}
    />
  );
}


   <FileTrees
      structures={struct}
      setValue={setValue}/>
```

- `setValue`: Has a type of `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>`
- `structures`: is an array of objects.

#### The Problem:

1. When i write the function like this

```js
export function FileTrees (structures, setValue){
   ....
}
```

i get the access to `data`, although when i call `setValue()`, i get an error which says `setValue` is not a function.

2. When i write the function like this

```js
export function FileTrees ({structures, setValue}){
   ....
}
```

i am able to call the `setValue()` without an error, also `structure` is valid but `data` is always an empty array [].

[SandBox Available Here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/determined-bouman-rhmc3n?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: I'd suggest you read more about [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) and [how to pass props to a component](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-props-to-a-component).

Comment: If you could provide a codesandbox link it would be great. As your data is empty array, could you try logging the `incoming` in useEffect?

Comment: What are you trying to do when you define data state as `useState<Array<{}>>([])`? It does not look like valid JavaScript code

Comment: @EduardoMatsuoka that is a valid typescript code. Saying that the initial state of data is an empty array of type `Array<{}>`.

Comment: @ShubhamJangle when i log incoming inside the effect, i get [] an empty array ? But note that the `convertObject` function is not a propblem as that function works fine.

Comment: @ShubhamJangle https://codesandbox.io/embed/determined-bouman-rhmc3n?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example, `export function FileTrees (structures, setValue){}`, is invalid. You must pass a single props object to the function.

Your second example is correct. 'Data' is empty because you initialize it as an empty array, and it will be empty as long as `convertObject` returns an empty array.

Comment: Thanks, but the return of `convertObject` is not an empty array. See the sandbox for the function `convertObject` https://codesandbox.io/embed/determined-bouman-rhmc3n?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @Saheed I don't see the function 'convertObject' in the link you provided.

Comment: It's located in the `filetree.tsx` file

Comment: @Saheed 'convertObject' should receive a non-array object, but you are passing it an array, because structures props is an array (oldStruct). Your typing for 'Structure' is not strict enough, that is why you do not see the error.

Comment: Absolutely ! Thanks Trever.

Comment: Had to change `const incoming = convertObject(structures)` to 
`const incoming = convertObject({structures})`